# Reseources for learning Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tutorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get started with Adobe Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/202/how-do-i-get-started-with-adobe-illustrator)

What are some good websites/tutorials/videos that will get me started with basic workflow concepts? I am not looking for "how to draw X", but general concept tutorials, although specific examples are not a problem as long as they teach general concepts.

Comment: Mods, please close this as a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has been answered [here,](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/202/how-do-i-get-started-with-adobe-illustrator/) "How do I get started with Adobe Illustrator?"

Answer (score 0):

There are some great tutorials all over the web, if you don't mind paying, http://www.lynda.com/ has some really informative tutorials. Lynda also has a youtube channel with a number of tutorials http://www.youtube.com/user/lyndapodcast.

In the best when learning programs, that really helped me the most.
But, just playing around with Illuratator, getting a feel for it through experience is the best way in my opinion, but if you're short on time, go for tutorials!