# Photoshop online tutorials

Tags: adobe-photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find tutorials for Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/178/where-can-i-find-tutorials-for-photoshop)

I have just started using **Adobe photoshop** and was looking for online tutorials highlighting all its features from beginner to advance level. Rather a beginner guide will be really helpful.

**Update**: I want to learn how to create images using photoshop, regarding different tools for editing an image and shortcuts for them on MacOS. I guess this will give me a start to use photoshop.

Kindly help me for the same.

Nitish

Comment: Please try to improve your question as per comments in the following, *closed*, question: [Where can I find tutorials for Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/178/where-can-i-find-tutorials-for-photoshop)

Comment: @koiyu : I have edited my question. It will be great if you help me out now.

Comment: @kolyu : If you can ask to improve the question, be the one to answer it.

Comment: @downvoter : Kindly tell me the reason so I may improve.

Comment: Nitish-  Unfortunately "I want to create images" encompasses every feature Photoshop has - PS exists solely to "create images".  If you have a question about the benefits/restrictions of a specific tool in Photoshop, people here can help you.  If you just need "introduction to Photoshop" tutorials, there are many other sites out there and they are not hard to find.

Comment: @farray : Glad you told me. But when you started, you too must be following some tutorials which might have helped to know photoshop better. I am just asking you to share them. It is no trouble in searching for tutorials. it is the recommended tutorials I was interested in. I hope you get me what I am trying to bring out.

Comment: This is not an appropriate place for this question. This site is about the profession of Graphic Design and its principles, not about how to use Photoshop. Sure a quick question about how to do a particular thing in Photoshop is acceptable (but kind of annoying), this is far too broad. Try google.

Comment: I think we were a bit hasty on this, as it asks for getting started from really 0 experience. (Which especially can be seen after the edit; if you have zero experience, it's quite hard to know what to ask for). Moreover, I vote this should be reopened as http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/202/how-do-i-get-started-with-adobe-illustrator is open too and has spawned some good answers. There is some [discussion on the meta](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48/closing-consistency) about closing consistency and tutorial questions.

Comment: @Nitish: I have reopened the question, but more context would be helpful because as it stands now this is technically a duplicate question.

Comment: @Nitish.  I was one of the downvoters and I explained prior.  Further to that, yes - everybody starts *somewhere*.  My problem with your question is that it essentially is "I am searching for tutorials" which indicates that you need a search engine, not a Q/A site.  In fact, typing "Photoshop tutorials" into Google brings up "...for beginners" as the second suggestion, and returns 2 million results with the first result being "50 Great Photoshop Tutorials for Clever Beginners".  The second result has "12 Beginner Tutorials".

Comment: (cont'd) If you have tried out the tutorials on other sites and found them lacking, or confusing, or have specific questions - this site could be the place for you.  We have plenty of members who could answer "Why does dodge/burn do what it does?" or "How do I achieve Complicated effect?"  But most of the people on this site are familiar with the tools of the trade, and to answer your question "where do I find tutorials?" they would have to hit a search engine.  You might as well skip the middle-man...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've never touched Photoshop before, start with the **Help**, which is included with the install. Not only it covers up all the aspects of the software, but also it links to official tutorial videos. And if the Adobe Help Air application is too heavy or constantly updating, the help contents are also available as [40+ MB PDF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/photoshop_cs5_help.pdf).

[**Learn Photoshop CS5**](http://www.adobe.com/support/photoshop/gettingstarted/index.html) is a good landing page to start and all the video tutorials can be found from [**AdobeTV** website](http://tv.adobe.com/show/learn-photoshop-cs5/).

If you're after those still convinced that official sources are good in quality, take a look at [**Adobe Photoshop CS5 Classroom in a Book**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321701763). In my opinion the Classroom in a Book -series have good introductory examples with relatively easy hands-on exercises.

Remember that Photoshop is just a tool and as such pretty versatile: you could do ia. photo editing, vector graphics, animation, 3D, digital painting or websites with it. When you get the grasp of the basics of the software, there's still much to learn, but those sources should help you to get to started and—in time—you will think the software less and the design product more.