# How to make an area in illustrator transparent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, transparency

So I want to have an empty star in my object; almost like a hole in the middle but star-shaped. How can I chop out the star shape in my object and make it transparent?

Comment: Wellcome to GD.SE. Do you know what a compound path is?

Comment: Now I do! I'll give it a try tomorrow

Comment: If it's not an image, you might want to use `Window > Pathfinder`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get started with Adobe Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/202/how-do-i-get-started-with-adobe-illustrator)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Pathfinder` is your friend, for things like this.

Starting with my two paths (rectangle and star).

[image: 1]

Make sure the object that you want to punch out is on top of the object you want to make the hole in.

[image: 2]

Open your `Pathfinder` (Window > Pathfinder).  I like to keep mine pinned to the toolbar on the right, because it gets used a lot.  Make sure that both paths are selected and press the circled option (Minus Front).

[image: 3]

That will give you this result:

[image: 4]

As you can see, the two paths have now been combined into a `Compound Path` and the star is now a hole in the rectangle.

[image: 5]